# Image height is halved after transformation from VideoCapture to Mat object

Tags: c++, image, visual-studio, opencv

The operations I did were quite simple:

I read an .avi file with a dimension of 1280x720, stored one frame of the video to a Mat object and displayed it.

Here is part of the code:

```
VideoCapture capL;
capL.open("F:/renderoutput/cube/left.avi");
Mat frameL;
cout << capL.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH) << ", " << capL.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT) << endl;

for (;;)
{
    capL.read(frameL);
    cout << frameL.size() << endl;
    if (frameL.empty())
        break;

    imshow("Output", frameL);
    waitKey(200);
}
......
```

But the dimensions of the capL and frameL are not he same, with the former being 1280x720 and latter 1280x360. Why is this happening? I have been using OpenCV 3.3.1 in Visual Studio for quite a long time and some day this happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the video is interlaced. So you have only half height of it in every frame.

[image]